# Can NativeScript SideKick run iOS apps on Windows?

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, nativescript

I have been recently experimenting with NativeScript and I have come across NativeScript SideKick which is suppose to build iOS apps in Windows using a cloud feature.

[NativeScript SideKick](https://www.nativescript.org/nativescript-sidekick)

But how can you run this build in an iOS emulator on Windows, has anyone tried this before?

Comment: Don't think so. ios simulator  runs on mac.

Comment: However, you can still run the app on your ios devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [@JenLooper](https://github.com/jlooper) in this [video 9.25s](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u19wHXXzpPc&feature=youtu.be&t=1165), she states that it is/will by possible but building app via cloud

Answer (score 1):

Yes and NO.

**YES**
Using the cloud build feature you can build for iOS and run this build on a connected iOS device AND/OR publish to the iOS App store.

**NO**
There is currently no emulator fo IOS that will run on windows.